# Expected is not part of std library

Tags: c++, error-handling

I used to use Expected in old framework to return either value or Error .

```
Expected<int a> foo () ;
```

I would like to use it and I headred that it Expected is now a part of std library
but
`Std::expect <int a> foo ();`  returns ERROR `Expected is not part of std libary`
Where can I find Expected libarary ?
What is the simplest way to retrun an Error or a value from fucntion in C++ ?

Comment: `std::expected` is a purposed feature that is not in the standard yet. Besides that, you have to show exact error messages and code as a [mcve]. `Expected<int a>`, `Std::expect <int a> ` and `Expected is not part of std libary` don't match and the error message is not a copy and past.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/c75ipk/why_stdexpected_is_not_in_the_standard_yet_is_it/

Comment: `c++` is case sensitive.

Comment: @drescherjm  WOOW , you must be kidding !

Comment: @t.niese 
you understand it wrong. Expected<int a> is how I used to use it.
Std::expect <int a> is what I am using now.

Comment: @HazemAbaza as said in an earlier comment, c++ is case sensitive. So for `Std::expect`, `Std` is wrong because `std` has to be lowercase, the same is with  `Expected<int a>`, it would be `expected`. And I'm pretty sure the compiler does not have a typo like `libary` in the error message, and I'm not aware - but there I might be wrong - that there is any compiler that writes `is not part of std library` as error message. There are various 3rd party implementation of `expected`, but it is not part of the std yet.